# Item is not being added in the dropdown list #Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have added a dropdown list in webform and added two item through edit item option. While debugging this page i am adding a new item (have used a text box and a button for this). It is getting displayed in the drop down list while run time only once i close the session and open again it is getting disappeared.

The Code for this is:

**In .aspx page:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="82px">
<asp:ListItem Text = "Select" Value="-1" Selected = "true"> </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Item1" Value="Wrigley"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text = "Item2" Value="Sigma"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="Bt_Save" runat="server" Text="Save" Visible = "false" onclick="Bt_Save_Click" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TB_CName" runat="server" Visible="False" Width="123px" 
 ontextchanged="TB_CName_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

**In .aspx.cs page**

```
protected void Bt_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String NewCustomer = TB_CName.Text.ToString().Trim();
        if(NewCustomer!="")
        {
          DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(NewCustomer, NewCustomer));
          TB_CName.Text = null;
          DropDownList1.Visible = true;
          Bt_Save.Visible = false;
          TB_CName.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
          Validater_CName.Visible=true;
        }
    }
```

What do I have to do to get the changed dropdown list every time i add i new item. Please post your suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: ***i close the session*** - Do you mean closing the browser window/browser tab?

Comment: Are you saving these new items to a database or some other storage ? If not, how are you expecting them to re-appear when you start a new session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> displayed in the drop down list while run time only once i close the
>   session and open again it is getting disappeared.

You are missing a basic concept that HTML is state less.

Only reason you are seeing it 1st time is **ASP.Net** uses **ViewState** to persist the state between post back.  Once you closed the browser or tab (it doesn't matter), the state information are gone.

In order to persist the data, you need to store it in Database (or a file).

***Note:*** You can use ASP.Net Cache which is stored in server memory. However, Cache is shared by all pages, so  it is not what you want for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If you do like this, you cannot get the changed dropdownlist data. Instead of editing, you should use data source to get the data if you want changes data. Then your changing data save in database.

Comment: Thanks u all ...I got the missing part. I have bound it to database and now it is working fine.:)